# How to run a program for a specified amount of time?

Tags: c++, unix

For a computation intensive problem I want to limit the CPU time spent by the program: if the program doesn't find a solution within a given amount of time, I want the program to be terminated. Rather than having the program look for a solution forever, it should terminate if nothing is found. In case the platform matter, this is for UNIX. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Did you write this question because question [How to run algorithm in C++ for 40 second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9239909/1168156) was closed before you wrote your answer there? Or why did you do that?

Comment: Why are you ansering your own question within three minutes?

Comment: I had basically written the answer to the question you referred to, yes. I felt that this is indeed an interesting issue and I couldn't locate an answer using the technique I described. I realize that the original question may have been quite terse but personally I don't think it was unclear or vague at all.

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan: well, another question with a similar topic got closed before I quite answer it and I didn't see that it would work too well to get it reopened as there were lots of negative votes already. So I asked the question I understood - ... and answered it. If this is inappropriate behavior please let me know!

Comment: I see, but I dont agree. Questions are not placeholders for answers.

Comment: I think it's perfectly OK to post a question, and if you later discover that you were able to solve it to answer it yourself. That said, a suckerpunch question for which you already have a pastable answer which leaves zero time for anyone else to read it might be considered a little gauche, so maybe in the interest of decorum it'd be nice to wait 10 minutes or so, so this won't be seen as a "Look at my l33t codez" blog post. Otherwise, you could post the code on Codereview instead and ask for feedback, or you could do the always popular "phrase your answer as a question" and say "is this OK?".

Comment: @Kerrek: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. tldr; "never hesitate to ask and answer your own question". That said, you accepted answer doesn't answer the question asked, so I suspect that the questioner doesn't really care what question was asked or answered, and that's a bit weak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another POSIX solution that's single-threaded and self-contained is to use signals:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>

std::sig_atomic_t volatile done = 0;

void game_over(int) { done = 1; }

int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGALRM, game_over);
    alarm(5); // this program will self-destruct in 5 seconds

    while (!done)
    {
        do_my_thing();  // or whatever; make sure this returns frequently
    }
}
```

(This is one of the very few legitimate and crucial uses of `volatile`: We must prevent the compiler from optimizing out the `while (!done)` conditional, and the compiler doesn't see that `done` can be mutated, because it's never touched inside the loop body.)

POSIX discourages the use of `std::signal` in favour of its own, more powerful `sigaction`. Consult the manual if you're interested, but for the simple purpose of raising an alarm this solution appears to suffice.

If your program offers no interruption points at all (i.e. points at which you can check `done`), then you could also call `abort()` in the signal handler.

Comment: `alarm` measures realtime seconds, question specifies "CPU time spent by the program". This technique is useful in its place, but there are probably dupes of the question this answer actually answers.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You can use `setitimer` and handle `SIGVTALRM` instead if you want virtual process time instead.

Answer (score 5):

A possible approach is to set up a process limit of the desired time.  The UNIX limits set with `setrlimit()` are observed by the run-time environment and they support both a soft and a hard limit. When the soft limit is reached a signal is triggered which can be used e.g.  to set a flag indicating that the program should wrap up. When the hard limit is reached the program should be terminted (although this doesn't seems to work on MacOS). Here is a simple example program:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

sig_atomic_t finished = false;
void limit(int)
{
    finished = true;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGXCPU, limit);
    struct rlimit limit;
    limit.rlim_cur = 2;
    limit.rlim_max = 3;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &limit);

    unsigned long long i(0);
    while (++i && !finished)
    {
    }
    std::cout << "i=" << i << " flag=" << std::boolalpha << bool(finished) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Also note you can do this from the commandline with `ulimit -t`.

Comment: I think you're only allowed to mutate variables with whitelisted types inside a signal handler, and I'm not sure if `bool` is on the list. `sig_atomic_t` seems to be tailor-made for that purpose, though.

Comment: You are right: only a change to `sig_atomic_t` is guaranteed in a signal handler. I have adjusted the code correspondingly. Thank you!